# ajax created form doesn't trigger ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have a list that is created using a while loop and when the user clicks the delete button ajax is used to delete an entry in the database and redraw the list.  This all works fine until the user tries to delete another item, the button does nothing, no errors, the only way to get it working is to refresh the page.

I have changed the ajax so all it returns is a button with the same class as the original to see if I can at least get it to trigger an alert if nothing else but nope, nothing.

The AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.trash_btn').click(function(){
        alert('bob');
    var question = $(this).next('.id_question').val();
    var user = '<? echo $id; ?>';   
    alert(question+' '+user);
      $.msgbox("Are you sure you want to delete the selected question?", {  
        type: "error", 
        buttons: [
          {type: "submit", value: "Yes"},
          {type: "cancel", value: "No"}
        ]
      }, function(result) {

        if (result == 'Yes') {
            $.ajax({
               url: 'ajax/opinion_del.php',
               type:'POST',
               data: 'question='+ question +'&user='+user,
               success: function(response){
               $('#responses_table').html(response);
            },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
        } // End of success function of ajax form
          }); 
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

The relevant portion of table

```
<td class="details">
      <input type="button" name="del_question" value="" class="trash_btn">
      <input type="hidden" class="id_question" name="question_id" value="<? echo $row['questionID']; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" class="id_user" name="user" value="<? echo $id; ?>"  >      
</td>
```

AJAX output creating non working test button (was originally using JSON but trimmed it out for testing)

```
$smeg = '<input type="button" value="test" class="trash_btn">';
echo $smeg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing your event binding to a delegated event handler rather than a standard one. What's happening is that you're correctly binding to the element on page load, but when you update the DOM via your AJAX call, the binding is lost since you're removing the element that was bound to.

E.g.

```
$('.trash_btn').click(function(){
```

changes to:

```
$('#responses_table').on("click", ".trash_btn", function(){
```

Using a delegated event handler means the event handler is actually bound to the `#responses_table` element and when it fires, it checks the element referenced in `event.target` to see if it matches the selector you pass-in as the second argument to `.on()`. This way your event handler works even if you muck around the DOM and alter HTML.

The alternative would be to re-bind your `click` event handler after your update the DOM via your AJAX callback.